# Ruby - can you create a standalone object like in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, object

In javascript, you can create blank objects that are not an instance of anything. Like so:

```
foo = {
    bar: 12,
    fooFunc: function() {
        return this.bar;
    }
}
```

Is this(or something similar) possible in ruby?

Comment: You can singleton an instance from `Object` and that would be the same.

Comment: Hope this article will be useful http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/05/12/quickie-objects-in-ruby/

Comment: also take a look at OpenStruct which allow you to add attributes at later points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby has an [`Object` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html) from which all other objects inherit. From the Ruby docs:

> Object is the parent class of all classes in Ruby. Its methods are
>   therefore available to all objects unless explicitly overridden.
>
> Object mixes in the Kernel module, making the built-in kernel
>   functions globally accessible.

In Ruby 1.9:

```
Object.new.class #=> Object

Object.class #=> Class
Object.superclass #=> BasicObject

BasicObject.class #=> Class
BasicObject.superclass #=> nil
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Would you consider accepting this answer as correct, then?

Comment: I will indeed, but I am required to wait another two minutes before it lets me.